# Core Data: Count Number of Consecutive Days

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data

The Core Data model I've created contains a `Session` entity that has a `timestamp` attribute. I'm currently looking for an efficient way to query Core Data for the number of consecutive days. In other words, if a user has created a session every day for the past six days, then the number of consecutive days is equal to six.

At first glance, it doesn't seem that this problem is solvable with a clever query. Am I overlooking something?

An alternative solution would be to ask Core Data for a batch of sessions and manually count the number of consecutive days until the chain breaks. Are there any solutions that I'm missing?

Comment: Is there a "parent" entity which is containing the `Sessions`, I would add a computed property to that which iterates overs the sessions exactly like you said in you question. Don't worry about efficiency until you get it working.

Comment: And parsing in a loop is not "manual"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a nice way to do this is to override `awakeFromInsert` where presumably you are creating the timestamp. Right there you could query the previous days (easy with a predicate comparing beginning and end of day) and store the number. I think this is not exaggerated or redundant, and storing an `int` is cheap.

Now the logic in your program becomes enjoyably easy: the number of days is readily available; you can compute the historic record of consecutive sessions; you can easily find all days in the sequence, including more than one sessions a day, etc.

Comment: While the solution would work, I don't like the idea of storing information in a session that depends on another session. This will also complicate session management. If a session is deleted, for example, the number of consecutive days stored in other sessions would need to be updated.

Comment: I don't see a problem with this. The value is a historic value so it should not be changed later. (This would be like editing log files.) If you really need to delete sessions (which also would be like editing log files), handle the case that they are not available any more, but the stored number is still true. Session management is not complicated by this in any way.

Comment: I'm going to adopt your approach since it offers a number of additional benefits. It makes other queries much easier, such as querying for the longest streak.